# How to include xml files in an OSGi bundle with bndtools?

Tags: osgi, bndtools

How to include an xml file in an OSGi bundle with bndtools  without the use of maven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -includeresource or Include-Resource directive, which are explained here:

- http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/820-instructions.html
- http://bnd.bndtools.org/heads/include_resource.html

The -includeresource one is preferred. A simple example:

```
-includeresource: static=static
```

Includes the resources which are in the 'static' folder of the project into the bundle in the 'static' folder.